# electron app can't require ipc from html file

Tags: javascript, node.js, ipc, electron

I have an electron app that I have built. From my main process I open a new window with:

```
  electron = require('electron')
  const {globalShortcut} = require('electron')
  const app = electron.app
  runnerWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: width, height: height})
  var path = `file://${__dirname}/app/template/index.html`
  console.log(path)
  runnerWindow.loadURL(path)
  runnerWindow.webContents.openDevTools()
```

Then from inside that html I call:

```
if (window.module) module = window.module;
const ipc = require('electron').ipcRenderer
```

The error I get is:

`Uncaught TypeError: require(...).ipcRenderer is not a function`

Why cant I require ipc from the file? I have other windows I open and use ipc but it doesnt work for this particular window.

Comment: Looks like the error is that you're trying to do `require('electron').ipcRenderer()` (notice the invocation parentheses)

Comment: @nem035 I tried adding (), same error. Also in my other window code I call without () and it works.

Comment: I meant that the error exists **because you are adding ()**.

Comment: @nem035  Im not sure what to change.  this is the line that is causing the error: const ipc = require('electron').ipcRenderer    . what do you suggest it be?

Comment: I just tried that in the electron project I'm currently working on, and: Works For Me. So your error is somewhere else - you need to show all the JS that is coming above those two lines, in the html file. (And if there is no code, why are you restoring `module` ?)